Model parameter averaging in Bagging
I wonder if the following bagging method is used in practice, or at least any reference for this.
Assume that we sample (sub)-datasets from the original training set, and train $n$ many logistic regression models with parameters $\theta_{i}$, $i = 1, 2, \dots, n$.
As far as I know, the usual way of bagging is to apply majority voting or averaging $n$ outputs.
Now, my suggestion is to set a new model by simply averaging parameters as $\theta = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \theta_{i}$ and use this model. Obviously, this method only works when the model architectures are all same.
